# Insert text into file after a specific text

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to insert an output into a file...in the next line after a specific text.

In my output (Text1.txt) I have different lines with domain names:

```
hxxp://example1.com
hxxp://example2.com
```

I would like to insert this lines into another text file (Text2.txt) after the line with the text "URLs found" (Note: I don't know the line number).

```
bla
bla
bla
URLs found
hxxp://example1.com
hxxp://example2.com
bla
bla
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do this using sed:

```
sed -i '/URLs found/r Text1.txt' Text2.txt
```

When the pattern is matched, insert the contents of Text1.txt. The `-i` switch means that sed edits the file in-place.

Alternatively, you could do the same thing in awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[n++]=$0;next} 1; /URLs found/{for (i=0;i<n;++i) print a[i]}' Text1.txt Text2.txt > tmp && mv tmp Text2.txt
```

Read all of the lines in Text1.txt into an array. the `1;` means that every line in Text2.txt is printed. When the pattern is matched, the contents of the array are also printed.

Comment: How would you use this with a variable instead of a file (Text1.txt)?

Comment: Just found it: `sed -i "/$var1/a $var2" Text2.txt`

Comment: @Nanoserver, yes, you can use double quotes around your sed command string and then the shell will expand those variables. Just be careful, because any characters that are significant as part of a regular expression (e.g. `.` or `&`) will be interpreted by sed. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29613304/2088135) for more info on what you would need to do to reliably work with variables with arbitrary values.

Answer (score 3):

`sed` makes it really easy:

```
sed -i '/URLs found/ r Text1.txt' Text2.txt
```